# How long are Westworld cycles?

Tags: westworld-2016, westworld

The Westworld park has an overarching story arc that continuously loops, and customers pay to visit the park at the beginning of a loop. Early in the show, we're shown Dolores looping the same morning repeatedly, making the loop appear relatively short. However, mention is made of attractions that take fair amounts of travel to get to and time required to participate in. Later episodes also make it seem like the cycles are longer than they appeared earlier.

How long are the Westworld cycles or loops?

I'm primarily interested in the new version, but if this answer only comes from earlier content, that's fine too.

Comment: As long as needed.

Comment: This is actually a fairly interesting question. The way the show presents them, they almost seem daily (but obviously that would not be that case).

Answer (score 8):

The very short answer is that some storylines take longer to cycle around than others. It's worth noting that short plots probably won't play out a second time if the guests have already experienced them since the entire park is designed to loop in a way that makes it **a fun place for the guests to take part in without repeatedly coming up against repetition.**

Dolores' primary cycle, for example (drops the can, picked up by Teddy or a guest, attack on the ranch, dinner with daddy or raped/seduced by guest) only takes a single day. If a guest takes her with them on a side-quest, the cycle is broken and the other protagonists join in other storylines or just idle somewhere.

[image]

---

In the previous Westworld film, the cycles seem to be keyed so that there's simply a schedule of activities for the duration of their guest's stay, with stuff going on each and every day; banquets, tourneys and parties for the guests to enjoy.

> **TECHNICIAN THREE:** *The Black Knight won’t be repaired until tomorrow afternoon. Switch to another scenario.*
>   **TECHNICIAN FOUR:** *—we have programmed infidelity in the Queen as of two minutes ago.*
>   **TECHNICIAN FIVE:** *Schedule the Indian attack for dawn—*
>   **TECHNICIAN SIX:** *I have the banquet for delivery at five-thirty if that conforms—*
>   **TECHNICIAN SEVEN:** *Well, I think we can arrange for her to—*
>   **TECHNICIAN EIGHT:** *Yes, he can be Sheriff if he wants, the Sheriff was just killed. Okay, program—*

Comment: What is the source for that narrative department image? Are there others?

Comment: @Skooba - It was one of the easter eggs from the official Westworld website. There was only one of these.

Comment: @Skooba in case it helps, those are also called "flow charts" which can be used for the description of software. Their use is typical in the demonstration of software implemented utility patents attached as figures. It was actually really cool to see it here, thought Valorum created it as a real quality answer.

Comment: Well, on a second look, it is sort of a "toy" flow chart really, but still cool.